# why are special characters read false from file

Tags: c++, special-characters, ifstream, ofstream

Hi my program saves some settings (mostly string) to a text file, to retrieve them later, but alas!  The special characters come back unrecognizable!

saveSettings saves the strings one by one...

```
void email::saveSettings(string filename){
    ofstream savefile(filename.c_str(),ios::out | ios::trunc);
    email settingsemail(this);
    savefile <<mailprog<<endl;
    ...
```

loadSettings retrieves them...

```
bool loadSettings(string filename){
    char chtemp[255];
    ifstream savefile(filename.c_str(), ios::in);
    if (savefile.is_open()){
    savefile.getline(chtemp,255);
    mailprog=chtemp;
    savefile.getline(chtemp,255);
    smtp=chtemp;
    ...
```

some text includes the letter 'é', which is read back as '8'

thank you for any hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should consider use a unicode version of getline : )

See [this article](http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/) for further info

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `ios::binary` to your stream constructor flags.